# Select from DynamicNamed Table which is Based on Static Table's Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Once more I need help from all of u..

I have Unknown numbers of Dynamic Tables in SQL DataBase

Just like Below,

```
=>User_Master
UserCode UserName
aaa       AAA
bbb       BBB

=>aaa_EmailInfo
UserCode    EmailId
aaa       aaa@gmail.com
aaa       aaa1@gmail.com

=>bbb_EmailInfo
UserCode    EmailId
bbb       bbb@gmail.com
bbb       bbb1@gmail.com
bbb       bbb2@gmail.com


Declare @CheckEmail VARCHAR(500) = 'aaa@gmail.com'

SELECT

    User_Master.UserCode,

    (SELECT User_Master.UserCode+'_EmailInfo'.EmailId FROM User_Master.UserCode+'_EmailInfo') EmailId

FROM User_Master
```

Here,
**User_Master is Static Table,
But aaa_EmailInfo and bbb_EmailInfo are Dynamically generated with Named on UsedCode..
Now i want to Check that @CheckEmail is Exist in Dynamic Tables on Not??**

How is it Possible??

Can anyone Suggest me SELECT Query ???

Comment: Why do you use dynamically generated tables? Just make on table `EmailInfo` and use a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: Yaah,, Right, But now mostly i completed my project with above coding, so now its not possible to change everything, thus i have to find solution on this way.. so can u please help me for this???

Comment: You will not be very happy with this database model, believe me. For the dynamic query read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: I do agree with comments above; but since you are on a path of no return, I have suggested an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_executesql`. The details are given [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) You can use COUNT(*) to determine if @CheckEmail exists in a table or not.

```
DECLARE @CheckEmail VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @Cnt int;

SET @CheckEmail = 'aaa@gmail.com';
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @cntOUT = count(*) 
   FROM User_Master.UserCode'+'_EmailInfo'+' WHERE EmailID = @CheckEmail';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@CheckEmail VARCHAR(500), @cntOUT int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @cntOUT=@cnt OUTPUT;
SELECT @cnt;
```